# Any open source software for monitoring MySQL performance?

Tags: mysql, optimization, performance

I'm working on improving the performance of a MySQL server. I'm looking for something to monitor the performance of MySQL (as query per second) over time so that I can measure any improvements I make.

Are their any easy to use open source software that does this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the tool [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/).  It's just like `top` in the *nix world, but for MySQL itself.  And it basically does exactly what you are asking...

As far as other optimization techniques, I personally really like using [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) for testing MySQL queries.  Basically, I create a simple script that does nothing but execute the query I want to improve.  Then, I run AB on it with different concurrency settings.  The benefit is that you get an idea on how the query scales, not just how fast it runs.  Who cares if a query is fast for a single run. What you really care about is how fast in runs with load.  So:

```
<?php
$my = new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass);
$my->query('SELECT foo');
```

Then, using AB:

```
ab -c 10 -n 10000 http://localhost/path/to/my/test.php
```

Then, by adjusting the concurrency parameter (`-c 10`) you can test for different concurrent load.  That way, you can really look at how your tweaks effect the exact query rather than *guessing* with other metrics.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL workbench should do.

http://wb.mysql.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked your question a long time ago - but I just happened across it and wanted to share another tool with you. Baron Schwartz of [Percona](http://www.percona.com) started [innotop](https://code.google.com/p/innotop/), which is a next generation mytop. It adds advanced InnoDB monitoring on top of server status and query analysis. If you are running CentOS, it is included in the EPEL repository.